# Two ngDialogs side by side

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dialog, ng-dialog

I want to open a ngDialog which has a button to open another ngDialog.
Now the second one should align right to the first one.

The problems I encountered are:
1. I cannot interact with the first dialog anymore when the second one is opened.
2. The alignment right next to the first dialog is hard for me. (I guess this is just css practice)

I'll work out a minimal example later and post it here. But maybe someone got an idea already.

Comment: I feel it's rather hard to put up a minimal example with all the files it needs to work. But I'm sure someone else had that problem already! Any ideas? :/